# deserializing issue w3c.dom.Element

Tags: java, jaxb, deserialization

here is simple dto

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class MessageDto {
        
        private Long Id;
        private Element message;
    
    }
```

and Controller

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SendController {

    private final SendService sendService;

    @PostMapping
    public void sendMessage(@RequestBody MessageDto message) {
        sendService.sendMessage(message);
    }
```

this method make an Element

```
private Element marshal(Object element) {
        try {
            Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.marshal(element, new DOMResult(document));
            return document.getDocumentElement();
```

this is Jaxb pojo that i use as argument in marshal method

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Request", propOrder = {
    "test"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Request", namespace = "some.test.name.space")
public class Request {

    protected String test;

 
    public String getTest() {
        return testing;
    }

    public void setTest(String value) {
        this.test = value;
    }

}
```

when i try to send  MessageDto to this controller from another java application i got an error

nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem deserializing property 'message' (expected type: [simple type, class org.w3c.dom.Element]; actual type: `org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl`), problem: Can not set org.w3c.dom.Element field MessageDto.message to org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl